# Kotlin value class in Spring Expression Language

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-el

i have my value class:

```
@JvmInline
value class DeviceId(val value: String)
```

and I would like pass deviceId as a key for cache:

```
    @CachePut(cacheNames = ["deviceCache"], key = "#deviceId.value")
    fun save(deviceId: DeviceId, device: Device): Device {
        return repository.save(deviceId, device)
    }
```

but i get a error from IDE:
`Cannot resolve property or method 'value' (dynamic property?)`

What is the correct way to pass value object in SpEL?

Comment: In Java there is no `DeviceId`. The `deviceId` parameter is just a `String`. So perhaps just directly write `#deviceId`? (I don't know SpEL)